# How to make the first Checkbox to be Automatically Checked upon loading with FormArray in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms, angular9

Good day all, I have two checkbox that I used FormArray for and i want the first Checkbox to be automtically checked/selected when i run the Aplication..Please how do i go about it? See my code below

```
 Checkboxform: FormGroup;
 checkboxValue: FormArray; 
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.Checkboxform = this.formBuilder.group({
      checkArray:this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
  }

 onCheckboxChange(e) {
    this.checkboxValue = this.Checkboxform.get('checkArray') as FormArray;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.checkboxValue.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
     this.checkboxValue.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value == e.target.value) {
          this.checkboxValue.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
   // console.log(checkboxValue);
    console.log(this.checkboxValue)
```

}

My Component.html look like this

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <h5>{{"Select Matching Criteria" | localize}} </h5>
                                   <form [formGroup]="Checkboxform" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >

                                    <div *ngFor="let data of Criteria; let i=index">
                                      <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" [value]="data.id" 
                                       (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
                                        {{data.category}}
                                      </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button>submit</button>
                                  </form>
                                   
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Please I need help on this..

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786403/set-default-values-to-formarray-in-angular-6

Comment: @MaxK ,No, i want the checkbox to be selected Automatically upon loading, am getting the Data from Database and storing in the Array that i call Criteria in my Component.html

Answer (score 1):

After your comment I hope I got you right and this will solve your problem:

First of all I would recommend to use a normal `FormGroup` instead of the `FormArray` for this use case. Then loop over your `Criteria` list and create `FormControls` for each item. As you stated that the first checkbox should be checked by default I used `index === 0` as input for the `FormControl` therefore the value will only be `true` for the first one and `false` for all the others.
I reduced the complexity here by reducing your `Criteria` object to only strings.

```
Criteria:string[] = ['criteria1', 'criteria2','criteria3'];

Checkboxform: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.Checkboxform = this.formBuilder.group({});


    this.Criteria.forEach((criteria,index) => {
       this.Checkboxform.addControl(criteria,new FormControl(index === 0))
    })
}
```

}

Now you need to adopt this in your template by adding the `formControlName`:

```
<form [formGroup]="Checkboxform">
  <div *ngFor="let data of Criteria; let i=index">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="data"/>
      {{data}}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as adding the `checked` attribute to your code. Just one line

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of Criteria; let i=index">
      <label>
          <input 
              type="checkbox" 
              [value]="data.id" 
              (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" 
              [checked]="i === 0"  ///////// Add this line, if the index is 0, it will get checked
          />
          {{data.category}}
      </label>
 </div>
```